# SVG ― click halts animation in Chromium and Safari

Tags: animation, safari, svg, box2d, chromium

right now I have totally no idea what could cause this strange bug and I hope to able to describe it as good as possible, but the code has grown big and to post all of it wont result in a clear question.

**1. Setup:**

A Box2dWeb animation in the background, where the triggering of the `Step()` method is done by `window.requestAnimationFrame` following the game loop implementation [here in the »That's it« section](http://nokarma.org/2011/02/02/javascript-game-development-the-game-loop/index.html). Every time the »draw« method is called, the b2body's transformation is handed over to a `<div>` and to a `<g>`. The `<div>` sets up the desired animation and the `<g>` acts as monitor of the body and resides into an inline `<svg>`.

Clicks are globally caught and if the user clicks on the `<div>` or on the `<path>` the target gains focus what leads to applying forces on the b2body.

**2. Bug:**

All in all everything works as expected, the animation runs fluid for the `<div>` and its corresponding `<g>`, clicking on both, the focus state changes correctly, **BUT** in chromium and Safari the `<g>` stops showing up the animation, when the user clicked on the `<g>`.

Here is the code that is used to set the transformation from the b2Body to the `<g>`:

```
function draw(){
    var str = this._sprite.transform;
    var mtrs = this._transformItem.matrix;
    mtrs.a = str.a1;
    mtrs.c = str.a2;
    mtrs.e = str.a3;
    mtrs.b = str.b1;
    mtrs.d = str.b2;
    mtrs.f = str.b3;
    this._transformItem.setMatrix( mtrs );
}
```

where `this._transformItem` points to `<g>.transform.baseVal.getItem( 0 )` and `this._sprite.transform` to a transform matrix of custom typ.

Here is the code to catch the clicks:

```
function getClickTargets( target ){
    var targets = { 'sprite' : null, 'link' : null };
    while( target ){
    if( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && 
        targets.link == null ){
        targets.link = target;
    }

    if( target.hasAttribute &&
        target.hasAttribute( 'data-sprite-id' ) && 
        targets.sprite == null ){
            targets.sprite = this._stage.getSpriteById( 
                target.getAttribute( 'data-sprite-id' ) );
    }

    if( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'path' ){
        var attr = target.getAttributeNS( NS, 'monitor-for-sprite' );
        if( attr != '' ){
            targets.sprite = this._stage.getSpriteById( attr );
        }
    }

    if( targets.link != null && target.sprite != null ){
        break;
    }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
        return targets;
};
```

In FF, IE9/10, Chrome and Opera everything runs as it should and the only thing that causes the misbehavior is that a »click« happens with a `<path>` as target. The matrices a correct because the animation keeps on running correct for the `<div>`.

What could cause this, where should I search, does anybody has an idea or had a similar bug?

**EDIT:**

Might this be caused by the fact that the events are caught and processed »asynchronously« to the overall running »update ticks« ?

**Edit 2:**

I noticed that the same problem occurs if I am starting the web inspector and watch the elements, but than all `<g>` elements freeze.

**Edit 3:**

I have got it running now, at least in chromium, but I guess Safari will do it also. I slightly changed the »draw« function to this:

```
function(){
    var str = this._sprite.transform;
    var mtrs = this._transformItem.matrix;

    mtrs.a = str.a1;
    mtrs.c = str.a2;
    mtrs.e = str.a3;
    mtrs.b = str.b1;
    mtrs.d = str.b2;
    mtrs.f = str.b3;



    //this._transformItem.setMatrix( mtrs ); //old line
    this._transformList.replaceItem( 
        this._transformList.createSVGTransformFromMatrix( mtrs ), 0 ); //new working line
}
```

If somebody knows why it only works with a new »SVGTransform« it would be nice to let me know. Otherwise I assume that this is a kind of bug.